# Is this a bug of iOS background location updates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, location

I have created an app which uses location updates in the background.When it goes to background ,then i start one background Task that is timer to call startUpdatingLocation for every 30 seconds,another timer to call stopUpdatingLocation after startUpdatingLocation.I write a LogTool to record app info when it is in background.I know the app.backgroundTimeRemaining is the same no matter the app is in background or foreground when CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation(Am i right ?),but it will be reseted to 180s When CLLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation.I used iPhone5s ,iOS 8.3.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
WWLOG(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations");
[LogTool writeContentToFile:@"locationManager didUpdateLocations"];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[LogTool writeContentToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"backGroundRemainingTime:(%f)",app.backgroundTimeRemaining]];
```

}

The app goes well for hours in background,but suddenly the app.backgroundTimeRemaining change to about 160s.Is this a bug ?
Here is a part of record.

> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 00:00:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)

***It goes well,then...***

> 2015-12-10 04:44:39 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:44:39 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:44:40 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:44:40 backGroundRemainingTime:(179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)
> 2015-12-10 04:44:41 time:2015-12-10 04:44:36 sessionId:3C95D7CC-E9D3-4B58-BCC2-384CB3EE5A47 lat:22548016l lon:113955506l accuracy:5000l
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.940208)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.771241)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.730064)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.702347)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.678130)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:01 backGroundRemainingTime:(160.546829)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:05 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:05 backGroundRemainingTime:(157.161099)
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:06 locationManager didUpdateLocations
>
> 2015-12-10 04:45:06 backGroundRemainingTime:(156.088492)